# How to test a sandbox module

Tags: community-official-site

I found a [sandbox module](http://drupal.org/sandbox/xandeadx/1782036) that I want to test.

What should I do to use it on my site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to get a version of [git](http://git-scm.com/) for your machine.  On Windows, [TortiseGIt](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) works reasonably well.  You can then use that to checkout a version of the sandbox module.  If there are patches, you can [apply](http://drupal.org/patch/apply) them to the module.  Then you just need to upload the module to your Drupal site with your normal methods (don't forget to run update.php).

A lot of this is made easier if you are using an IDE, as newer ones are well integrated with git.